# AS3 fzip: add image to zip

Tags: image, actionscript-3, zip

I'm trying to add images to a zip archive using **fzip**.
I have successfully added some text documents using character encoding UTF-8

this._files.addFileFromStringAt(i,fileName,regexTest(rules,fileData));

Here is the method from the Fzip class:

```
        public function addFileFromStringAt(index:uint, name:String, content:String, charset:String = "utf-8", doCompress:Boolean = true):FZipFile {
        if(filesList == null) {
            filesList = [];
        }
        if(filesDict == null) {
            filesDict = new Dictionary();
        } else if(filesDict[name]) {
            throw(new Error("File already exists: " + name + ". Please remove first."));
        }
        var file:FZipFile = new FZipFile();
        file.filename = name;
        file.setContentAsString(content, charset, doCompress);
        if(index >= filesList.length) {
            filesList.push(file);
        } else {
            filesList.splice(index, 0, file);
        }
        filesDict[name] = file;
        return file;
    }
```

When I try to add an image using this method, the image becomes unreadable. I have tried to open the two files (original and in compressed) in binary format, it seems that the new image has many 'c3' characters.

Here are the original and the generated files:

## Original

```
ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0201 0048
0048 0000 ffe1 1539 4578 6966 0000 4d4d
002a 0000 0008 0007 0112 0003 0000 0001
0001 0000 011a 0005 0000 0001 0000 0062
011b 0005 0000 0001 0000 006a 0128 0003
0000 0001 0002 0000 0131 0002 0000 001c
0000 0072 0132 0002 0000 0014 0000 008e
8769 0004 0000 0001 0000 00a4 0000 00d0
000a fc80 0000 2710 000a fc80 0000 2710
4164 6f62 6520 5068 6f74 6f73 686f 7020
```

## Compressed

```
c3bf c398 c3bf c3a0 0010 4a46 4946 0001
0201 0048 0048 0000 c3bf c3a1 1539 4578
6966 0000 4d4d 002a 0000 0008 0007 0112
0003 0000 0001 0001 0000 011a 0005 0000
0001 0000 0062 011b 0005 0000 0001 0000
006a 0128 0003 0000 0001 0002 0000 0131
0002 0000 001c 0000 0072 0132 0002 0000
0014 0000 00c2 8ec2 8769 0004 0000 0001
0000 00c2 a400 0000 c390 000a c3bc c280
0000 2710 000a c3bc c280 0000 2710 4164
```

Comment: You're not alone in this problem! I decompressed an fzip-ed image and inspected it and the original in a hex editor. I found the fzip image and the original image were identical except that fzip had added 4 junk bytes at the front of the image.This happened both when saving compressed and when saving uncompressed. Both times, the 4 bytes were 0x0c 84 c6 37.

Comment: Has my response not solved the problem ?

Comment: I don't think so. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/V0e1yUXH You can see the function I'm using already takes in a byte array. I'm still investigating this problem and I'll post a solution here so others can find it.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that I was passing a Bytearray object to addFileToZip. Bytearrays apparently have 4 bytes of metadata at the front of the bytestream, so these four bytes were being written into the byte array I was saving to the zip along with the original stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the method `addFileAt` , it can be used to add a ByteArray.

```
public function addFileAt(index:uint, name:String, content:ByteArray = null, doCompress:Boolean = true):FZipFile
```

It works for images!